# Set values of column based on other column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, match

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
  ID     Score New.ID New.Score
  123     5      456          
  456     1      789          
  789     0      123
```

I would like to give the same scores to the New.ID column (which are just in a different order).

Desired result:

```
  ID    Score New.ID New.Score
  123     5      456         1
  456     1      789         0
  789     0      123         5
```

Code to reconstruct data frame:

```
ID <- as.factor(c(123,456,789))
Score <- c(5,1,0)
New.ID<- as.factor(c(456, 789, 123))
New.Score <- c(1,0,5)
dt <- data.frame(ID, Score, New.ID, New.Score)
```

**Update**

Desired output:

```
  Group  ID Score New.ID New.Score
     1 123     5    456         1
     1 456     1    789         0
     1 789     0    123         5
     2 555     1    999         0
     2 123     1    123         1
     2 999     0    555         1
```

So I am trying to attempt to use the function for each group. The ID `123` has score `5` in group 1, but in group 2 it has score `1`. And I only want to use the scores that appear within each group.

I tried with `ave`:

```
mtch <- function(x) {
  dt[match(x,dt$ID),"Score"]  
}

dt$New.Score <- ave(dt$New.ID, dt$Group, FUN = mtch)
```

But it gives me NA values.

Code for second df:

```
Group <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
ID <- as.factor(c(123,456,789, 555, 123, 999))
Score <- c(5,1,0, 1,1,0)
dt <- data.frame(Group, ID, Score, New.ID)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `match` should do the trick. Using the data you provided:

```
data <- data.frame(ID, Score, New.ID)
data$New.Score <- data[match(data$New.ID,data$ID),"Score"]
```

And then checking that it's our desired result:

```
identical(dt,data)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Can't accept yet due to the time limit :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: I have a small request, maybe you can help! The IDs are actually grouped. And the same ID could appear in a different group with a different score. My question is, how to apply this function on a group level. I tried to do something with `ave` but got NAs back. I updated my question with an example. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing - I think the question is different enough that this is considered "a new question". Could you please post a new question and I (or anyone) can answer it?