# Match values of column based on other column per groups

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a data frame where I would like to match the Score values of ID to New.Score.

The ID `123` has score `5` in group 1, but in group 2 it has score `1`. And I only want to use the scores that appear within each group.

This is my df:

```
  Group  ID Score New.ID New.Score
     1 123     5    456         
     1 456     1    789         
     1 789     0    123         
     2 555     1    999         
     2 123     1    123         
     2 999     0    555
```

And my desired output:

```
  Group  ID Score New.ID New.Score
     1 123     5    456         1
     1 456     1    789         0
     1 789     0    123         5
     2 555     1    999         0
     2 123     1    123         1
     2 999     0    555         1
```

I tried with `ave`:

```
mtch <- function(x) {
  dt[match(x,dt$ID),"Score"]  
}

dt$New.Score <- ave(dt$New.ID, dt$Group, FUN = mtch)
```

But it gives me NA values.

Code for df creation:

```
Group <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
ID <- as.factor(c(123,456,789, 555, 123, 999))
Score <- c(5,1,0, 1,1,0)
dt <- data.frame(Group, ID, Score, New.ID)
```

Comment: The `New.ID` column is missing so the `dt <- data.frame(...)` won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar approach as in my previous answer ([Set values of column based on other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333065/set-values-of-column-based-on-other-column)), but this time use an `interaction` in the matching. Something like this:

```
dt$New.Score <- dt[match(interaction(dt$Group,dt$New.ID) , 
                         interaction(dt$Group,dt$ID)), "Score"]

   #   Group  ID Score New.ID New.Score
   # 1     1 123     5    456         1
   # 2     1 456     1    789         0
   # 3     1 789     0    123         5
   # 4     2 555     1    999         0
   # 5     2 123     1    123         1
   # 6     2 999     0    555         1
```

**Data:**

```
Group <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
ID <- as.factor(c(123,456,789, 555, 123, 999))
Score <- c(5,1,0, 1,1,0)
New.ID <- as.factor(c(456, 789, 123, 999, 123, 555))
dt <- data.frame(Group, ID, Score, New.ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dt)`), grouped by 'Group', `match` the 'New.ID' with 'ID' to get the numeric index and use that to rearrange the 'Score' and assign (`:=`) it to 'New.Score'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, New.Score := Score[match(New.ID, ID)], Group]
dt
#    Group  ID Score New.ID New.Score
#1:     1 123     5    456         1
#2:     1 456     1    789         0
#3:     1 789     0    123         5
#4:     2 555     1    999         0
#5:     2 123     1    123         1
#6:     2 999     0    555         1
```